# "Law" or "principle" or "rule"?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, science

I write an essay on typography.
I want to keep it more or less informal but 
still with some structural highlights.

Typical presentation for central ideas (sort of "bullet points"), 
will be in such form:

- Statement: 
  [A postulation of a technical rule, based on experience 
  and  is believed to be a very probable, "strong" technical rule]
- Observation:
  [description of observation and possible connection with
  the statement]
  ....

I am looking for good synonyms for "statement" in such context.
It is declared globally, that the essay is  about **my own** treatment of results based on experience.
The statements are not laws or strict rules, but a verbal 
summaries of technical knowledge, and is a possible candidate for such rules.
In other words there is no aim to  prove something in the first place.
An observation is a description, how the statement can be experimentally
supported.

For example:

- Statement 1: 
  Straight text lines is the optimal glyph placement principle.
- Observation(s):
  Create different curvy text lines and observe the results
  ...

So it is sort of rule, sometimes obvious sometimes not, sometimes the rule itself is not explainable, still shows itself practically as a kind of global **technical rule** or potential "law".
The question is what would be a good word instead of "statement" here?

A more lively illustration of the principle in a dialogue:

Peter : Probably we can use the method 'B' to forge this tool?
Michael : Method 'A' works better. If you dig it you'll come 
to the method 'A'.

Answer (score 1):

How about *guidance*

> Advice or information aimed at resolving a problem or difficulty, especially as given by someone in authority.

[Oxford Dictionaries Online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/guidance)